# React Alt Babel IE9-10 Fails with no error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm currently developing an application with a React-Alt-Babel stack.
I had an issue with Promise on IE9-10, so I added babel-polyfill. I now get a blank page with no error on those browsers. It seems that Alt actions are not binded on Alt stores anymore.

Does anyone encounter such an issue? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There were two issues in my case:

- Alt version (0.18.x) was bugged, I had to downgrade to 0.17.9
- Babel didn't call super in constructor, I had to implement the following plugins :
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties",['transform-es2015-classes', {loose: true}]]